How many rows of data are deemed untenable and require a switch to a JSON column
Context
To describe the situation I find myself in currently, let's take the 3 tables relevant to this:
CREATE TABLE steam_user (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    steam_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    profile_url TEXT NOT NULL,
    avatar_url TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE achievement (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    display_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    icon_url TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    categories SMALLINT[] DEFAULT '{}' NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE achievements_on_steam_users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    steam_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,  /* foreign key */
    achievement_id INTEGER NOT NULL, /* foreign key */
    achieved BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    unlock_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
);

I'm pulling achievements for a specific set of games from the Steam API and then connecting them together in the achievements_on_steam_users junction table.
The problem
achievements_on_steam_users gains over 1000 rows every time i pull achievement data for a user. This will happen once every time a new user's data is queried on the site. I pull the state of all achievements from steam and then save it to my database.
Use Case
One of the pages required me to query all of these entries for one specific user. Optimally I'd prefer to be able to JOIN this query with the achievement table. Furthermore I would like to support a case, where users can reset their achievement data (on Steam). This is why I would prefer to have rows with the achieved = FALSE state in them and just update as I go, instead of only adding completed achievements to this list, that I'd then have to delete.
These are the two main queries that I'm worrying about:
SELECT *
FROM achievements_on_steam_users
WHERE steam_user_id = $1 /* some id */




QUERY PLAN




Seq Scan on achievements_on_steam_users  (cost=0.00..25.60 rows=1328 width=21)


Filter: (steam_user_id = 1)



SELECT *
FROM achievements_on_steam_users
INNER JOIN achievement ON achievements_on_steam_users.achievement_id = achievement.id
WHERE steam_id = $1 




QUERY PLAN




Hash Right Join  (cost=42.20..107.98 rows=1328 width=282)


Hash Cond: (achievement.id = achievements_on_steam_users.achievement_id)


->  Seq Scan on achievement  (cost=0.00..62.28 rows=1328 width=261)


->  Hash  (cost=25.60..25.60 rows=1328 width=21)


->  Seq Scan on achievements_on_steam_users  (cost=0.00..25.60 rows=1328 width=21)


Filter: (steam_user_id = 1)



Keep in mind that these times aren't indicative of a lot, since I currently only have test data (my own) in the database.
Question
Would it make sense to instead store these values in a json column directly inside of the steam_user table. I would define a schema similar to:
{
  //This could be any ID from the `achievement` table
  "333": {
    "achieved": true,
    "unlockTime": "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
  }
}

For those unfamiliar with steam achievements; the data inside of the achievement table changes very rarely and even then the IDs would never change. At best new IDs would get added.
Is that a good idea? Maybe someone more familiar with this volume of data can tell me if the queries would considerably slow down in this case?
For now all of my mitigations have been on the code side and I've worked around this, as of now, non-issue. However I'd like to mitigate the amount of rows before this actually gets released publicly, since I feel like the verbosity is unnecessary.

Querying JSON data (even when stored as JSONB) with search criteria dependent on values within the JSON is less efficient than querying the same data stored as appropriately indexed columns in separate rows. The database's ability to enforce referential integrity is also severely hindered by storing the references in JSON. Your fundamental problem appears to be one of inefficient handling of users' achievements. Only update each user's changed achievements or add their new achievements.

@JohnH I do want to only update the changed achievements for users, however it's possible that all user achievements could change at once (in the case of resetting progress). I could however only add achievements that have already been attained but then I would need to add and remove rows for every change in the future. Would that not increase the workload compared to updating existing rows?


Would it make sense to instead store these values in a json column directly inside of the steam_user table.

Very unlikely, unless your data is very dynamically defined and is rarely queried in its parts, only as a whole.
The JSON schema would have a far larger storage footprint. Your current schema incidentally can be improved by removing the unnecessary id column, and making the two FKs into a composite primary key.
CREATE TABLE achievements_on_steam_users (
    steam_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,  /* foreign key */
    achievement_id INTEGER NOT NULL, /* foreign key */
    achieved BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    unlock_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (steam_user_id, achievement_id)
);

Your current schema would take per row, and after calculating padding, 24 header bytes plus 24 bytes of data, for a total of 48 bytes per row, or 48000 bytes per user. Incidentally, Postgres is particularly bad for small rows, some DBMSs are much more efficient.
The JSON schema on the other hand, requires much more. It's hard to tell without actual data, but a quick check using a fiddle gives about 70kb for a single user. On top of that, it's much less efficient to query a single value.
So it only really makes sense to use this type of JSON structure when the whole blob is being queried always (or almost always), not when you need individual values. Even then, it's still against first principles of database design, because referential integrity can't be enforced, and would only be advised if you already have JSON or if performance demanded it for some reason.

What I don't really understand is why you need all those rows. It sounds as if you only actually need to know when that achievement_id was attained by the user, so you only need to store rows where achieved is true. Then you can have the schema:
CREATE TABLE achievements_on_steam_users (
    steam_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,  /* foreign key */
    achievement_id INTEGER NOT NULL, /* foreign key */
    unlock_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (steam_user_id, achievement_id)
);

Or for a JSON schema you can just use:
{
  //This could be any ID from the `achievement` table
  "333": "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
}


To explain the amount of rows. Most people who would use this type of website are achievement hunter types. It's likely that most of them would have a lot of these achievements already so the real use case number of rows wouldn't be far off from the maximum attainable number.
I thought it might be better to only update these later on instead of inserting, or worse in the case of resetting progress, deleting and then re-inserting these rows over and over.
However with your last schema I thought that I could technically leave out the achieved column since i can check for date > default.

No updating is worse than just inserting when you need. Why would you need to keep deleting and inserting, just insert what you need, like I said at the end?

I generally recommend against using sentinal values. If there's no need to know when a user reset an achievement, then allowing unlock_time to be NULL might be preferabe since it allows querying for achievements unlocked prior to a certain time withou knowing the magic sentinal value. Having a constant default for unlock_time when the column is declared NOT NULL conveys no more information than allowing NULL without a default. Consider retaining achieved from the original post and using unlock_time (rename?) with a default of NOW() as the state change time to support resets.

@Charlieface What would I do with the values then, once someone resets their achievement progress? I'd have to update the achieved and unlock_time for all of them or delete the rows entirely wouldn't I?

@JohnH The original unlock time in steam achievements is in unix time and is set to 0 on achievements that haven't been unlocked yet. Code side I'd have to change a few things to support NULL at all. Realistically I could remove the DEFAULT and nothing much would change code side, since I would be converting the value 0 to a timestamp value, which would produce the same outcome.
Would that be a preferable alternative?

Yes, you would delete them in the second example. Your exact use case was not clear to me, I thought there was no way to "revert" the achievement.

@Liryon, you needn't store the user achivement attributes with the same characteristics as returned by the Steam API, although doing so is likely to reduce the amount of code required. The important takeaways should be to avoid using JSON to record frequently queried data and to minimize the number of inserts, updates, and deletes. One other thing, make reasonable choices while getting the application working; however, don't spend excessive time on optimizations that might not be necessary. Maintainability is often much more important than optimal performance.

Never use an array of primary keys instead of a junction table to model an m-to-n relationship. That will perform worse, and you cannot have referential integrity.
To convince yourself, benchmark both solutions with realistic amounts of data or just write the SQL statement that joins the tables an take a look at it. The join statement for the data model with the arrays will look complicated, which usually is a bad sign.
